# Is there an all-in-one command for RPM to downgrade a package to an older version?

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm

I want to downgrade a couple RPMs.  Is there a switch combination for that?  For example, when upgrading, I usually run `rpm -Uvh foo.rpm` but my understanding is that the `-U` switch means that it only replace the package if it's older... so it won't work for downgrades.

Comment: Are you using YUM to do this work or do you have the RPM files locally already? I'd attempt using `yum downgrade <package>`.

Comment: @slm local rpm files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Using RPM

Try the following:

```
$ rpm -Uvh --oldpackage pkg1.rpm pkg2.rpm
```

*excerpt from rpm man page*

```
   rpm {-U|--upgrade} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   This upgrades or installs the package currently installed to a newer 
   version.  This is the same as install, except all other version(s) of the  
   package are removed after the new package is installed.

   --oldpackage
          Allow an upgrade to replace a newer package with an older one.
```

#### Using YUM + downgrade

With `yum` you should be able to do the following as well:

```
$ yum downgrade /path/pkg1.rpm /path/pkg2.rpm
```

#### Using YUM + history undo

If you previously had pkgX-1.0 installed and then upgraded it to pkgX-1.1, you should be able to use `yum history` to see this upgrade and `yum history undo` to revert this too.

*excerpt from yum man page on history*

> The undo/redo/rollback commands take either a single transaction id or
>   the keyword last and an offset from the last transaction (Eg.  if 
>   you've done  250 transactions, "last" refers to transaction 250, and
>   "last-4" refers to transaction 246).  The redo command can also take
>   some optional arguments before you specify the transaction.
>   "force-reinstall" tells it reinstall any packages that were installed 
>   in  that  transaction  (via install, upgrade or downgrade). 
>   "force-remove" tells it to forcibly remove any packages that were
>   updated or downgraded.
>
> The  undo/redo  commands  act  on the specified transaction, undo'ing
>   or repeating the work of that transaction. While the rollback command
>   will undo all transactions up to the point of the specified
>   transaction. For example, if you have 3 transactions, where package 
>   A;  B  and  C  where installed  respectively.  Then "undo 1" will try
>   to remove package A, "redo 1" will try to install package A (if it is
>   not still installed), and "rollback 1" will try to remove packages B
>   and C. Note that after a "rollback 1" you will have a fourth
>   transaction, although the  ending  rpmdb version (see: yum version)
>   should be the same in transactions 1 and 4.

To see your YUM history:

```
$ sudo yum history | head
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   120 | install httpd            | 2014-08-26 09:19 | Install        |    5   
   119 | install pydf             | 2014-08-22 17:11 | Install        |    1   
   118 | install xsel             | 2014-08-22 13:29 | Install        |    1   
   117 | install pastebinit       | 2014-08-22 13:26 | Install        |    2   
   116 | install xorg-x11-apps-0: | 2014-08-21 11:04 | Install        |    2   
   115 | remove adobe-release-x86 | 2014-08-21 02:18 | Erase          |    1   
   114 | update                   | 2014-08-21 02:15 | E, I, O, U     |   67  <
```

To undo a particular transaction:

```
$ sudo yum history undo 120
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit, tsflags
Undoing transaction 120, from Tue Aug 26 09:19:17 2014
    Dep-Install apr-1.5.1-1.fc20.x86_64                 @updates
    Dep-Install apr-util-1.5.3-1.fc20.x86_64            @updates
    Dep-Install fedora-logos-httpd-21.0.1-1.fc20.noarch @fedora
    Install     httpd-2.4.10-1.fc20.x86_64              @updates
    Dep-Install httpd-tools-2.4.10-1.fc20.x86_64        @updates
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.5.1-1.fc20 will be erased
---> Package apr-util.x86_64 0:1.5.3-1.fc20 will be erased
---> Package fedora-logos-httpd.noarch 0:21.0.1-1.fc20 will be erased
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.4.10-1.fc20 will be erased
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.4.10-1.fc20 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
...
```