# linux + how to fallback from yum -y update

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

we run by mistake the command yum -y update on some Linux machines

is it possible to perform fallback as was before we run the last yum update ?

and if yes what is the procedure ?

Comment: In theory it is possible using the 'downgrade' subcommand but it is fraught with danger.  Read up about the issues with downgrading before attempting a downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended yum `downgrade` subcommand is only useful to downgrade a few packages to the previous or a specific version of your choice.

What you should do is check `yum history` output and identify the problematic transaction, then run `yum history undo` on the transaction ID, which will revert that transaction. This is also explained in a few existing questions, check [Is there an all-in-one command for RPM to downgrade a package to an older version?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152457/is-there-an-all-in-one-command-for-rpm-to-downgrade-a-package-to-an-older-versio)
and also [Remove completely all packages I installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282434/remove-completely-all-packages-i-installed)